# Bug in AVAudioPlayer class?

Tags: iphone, ios4

I'll keep it short and sweet - I'm building an application just for practice before I buy myself the iPhone Developer Program.

I'm experimenting with the AVFoundation.framework and I keep running into a bug which will only let me play the first sound I initialize in my code. Do you think any of you could help me out? Thanks in advance!! :)

**view controller**

```
-(IBAction)play {
    if (segments.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        NSLog(@"Segment = 0");
        NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
        NSString *path = [bundle pathForResource:@"meow" ofType:@"wav"];

        if (path != nil) {
            NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
            AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url error:NULL];
            [player prepareToPlay];
            [player play];
        }
    }

    else if (segments.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
        NSLog(@"Segment = 1");
        NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
        NSString *path2 = [bundle pathForResource:@"meowloud" ofType:@"wav"];

        if (path2 != nil) {
            NSURL *url2 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path2];
            AVAudioPlayer *player2 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url2 error:NULL];
            [player2 prepareToPlay];
            [player2 play];
//          [player2 release];
        }
    }

    text1.textColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    text2.textColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    text3.textColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    text4.textColor = [UIColor clearColor];

}
```

When this code gets executed, only the **meow.wav** is executed, no matter which segment is selected.

Comment: You have some memory leaks in this code, but that shouldn't prevent the sound from playing correctly. I'll tackle the sound problems first: Is the correct text sent to the console when you select the second segment index? i.e. does the console show "Segment = 1"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has a couple of memory leaks. You allocate instances of AVAudioPlayer in your `play` method, but you never release those instances. See [Cocoa's memory management qguidelines](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/memorymgmt/memorymgmt.html) for details. Since the AVAudioPlayer instances need to remain in memory to play, the easiest solution is to add a member variable to your viewController class and set it up as a `retain` property.

For the sake of [Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself), I would also suggest adding a method which encapsulates all of the code needed to play a single wav file.

Here is how I would write this view controller:

> **MyViewController.h**

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
{
    AVAudioPlayer *player;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *player;
- (void)playWavFile:(NSString *)fileName;
- (IBAction)play;
@end
```

> **MyViewController.m**

```
@synthesize player;

- (void)dealloc {
    [player release];
}

- (void)playWavFile:(NSString *)fileName {
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];   
    NSString *path = [bundle pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"wav"];

    if (path != nil) {
        AVAudioPlayer *newPlayer;
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
        newPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url
                                                           error:NULL];
        [self setPlayer:newPlayer];
        [newPlayer release];

        [newPlayer prepareToPlay];
        [newPlayer play];
    }
}

- (IBAction)play {

    if (segments.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        [self playWavFile:@"meow"];
    }
    else if (segments.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
        [self playWavFile:@"meowloud"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I'll try it and report back. In the meantime, how can you [newPlayer release]; before you call prepareToPlay and play?

Comment: You can do that because of the line above it. `[self setPlayer:newPlayer]` makes use of the property accessor for the `player` member variable, which means that it is automatically retained (because the property was defined as a retain property). After that call is made, your viewController "owns" the player, so you can safely call `release` to balance out the call to `alloc`.

Comment: Crap... it doesn't work. I get:

**Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.**


2010-06-30 19:48:41.334 Merrrw![4713:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AVAudioPlayer initWithContentsOfURL:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6302f80'

Any ideas?

Thanks again for all the help. :)

Comment: Make sure the `filename` that gets passed into `initWithContentsOfURL` exists in XCode (i.e. you added it to the resources folder if it's a sound file).  You can also check the code at various steps with an NSLog to see if it all is working... also, shouldn't `[newPlayer prepareToPlay];` and `[newPlayer play];` actually be `[player prepareToPlay];` and `[player play];` ? Or am I not counting my retains correctly?  Just curious

Comment: @seanny94: Sorry, my fault. I forgot to include the error argument in the call to initWithContentsOfURL: I'll fix it in my code.

Comment: @IWasRobbed: Either one will do at that point, since the call to `[self setPlayer:newPlayer]` retains the variable, and `newPlayer` still contains a valid reference to it. If you were to display the value of each of those pointers, they would still point to the same thing (a single instance of `AVAudioPlayer`)

Comment: Thanks! :D I should have realized that myself, though. :/